# Why does my script fail after indentation?

Tags: shell, ksh

My code is failing after indentation. Tried many options but did not get any satisfactory outcome.

```
#!/bin/ksh

typeset -i destCount=1
dbRole="PHYSICAL STANDBY"
RMANPGM=cat
policy="CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE;"

if [[ ${destCount} -gt 0 ]] || [[ "${dbRole}" == "PHYSICAL STANDBY" ]]; then
    if [[ "${policy}" == "CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE;" ]]; then
        ${RMANPGM}<<-EOF
        run{
        CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO APPLIED ON ALL STANDBY;
        }
        exit
        EOF
     fi
else
    echo "Assuming archive deletion policy set as appropriate..."
fi
```

Tried several options for `"<<-EOF"` to remove the tab's as a here document method but no luck. If I add hash `<<#EOF` then it is working. However, I do not want to use `#` since it considered as comment in shell script.

Do we have any other way to run the commands after indentations.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Not a specialist of here docs, but from what I've tried, the second EOF should not be tabbed (just don't tab that line and it should work)

Comment: @Andre: I tried that too. Still no luck.

Comment: Im not sure why `#` is working perfectly here. Which I cant use.

Comment: Both untabbed and `#` works for me. Maybe a version problem ? Using "sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an indented here-document with `<<-LABEL`, the only indentation that will be removed from the document and its terminating `LABEL` will be actual tab characters (not spaces).  If you have indented using spaces, the shell will have difficulties finding the terminating `LABEL`.

Answer (score 0):

And regarding the hash [#] it can be used in here-doc as per “man ksh”.

<<[-]word

The shell input is read up to a line that is the same as word after any quoting has been removed, or to an end-of-file. No parameter substitution, command substitution, arithmetic substitution or file name generation is performed on word. The resulting document, called a here-document, becomes the standard input. If any character of word is quoted, then no interpretation is placed upon the characters of the document; otherwise, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic substitution occur, \new-line is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, ` . If - is appended to <<, then all leading tabs are stripped from word and from the document. If # is appended to <<, then leading spaces and tabs will be stripped off the first line of the document and up to an equivalent indentation will be stripped from the remaining lines and from word. A tab stop is assumed to occur at every 8 columns for the purposes of determining the indentation.

I have compared for both ksh88 & ksh93 and looks like the usage of “<<#” introduced in ksh93.

correct me if I misinterpreting.